# JavaScript innerHTML causing css to disappear on <button>

Tags: javascript, css, firefox, google-chrome

I have  a button tag with two spans inside;

```
<button><span><span id="buttonText">Save</span></span></button>
```

I'm trying to make it so that when you click the button the text changes so I have;

```
onclick="document.getElementById('buttonText').innerHTML = 'Saving...'; this.style.className"
```

Now funnily enough it works fine in IE8, but testing in Firefox and Chrome, both lose the css sliding doors styles I have set up on the button and the spans.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about manipulating nodeValue instead? `.firstChild.nodeValue` if memory serves me right.